# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera service on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera2, flashlight

I am developing an app that need to turn On Flash Light in android Lollipop (API 21 , 22)

But when I run it .

it show blew error , So I google it and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516539/android-camera2-bad-argument-passed-to-camera-service) but I can't understand how to solve problem !!

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.amir133.flashlight, PID: 15787
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera service
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:114)
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
    at $Proxy1.createDefaultRequest(Unknown Source)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:481)
    at com.example.amir133.flashlight.FlashLightUtilForL$MyCameraDeviceStateCallback.onOpened(FlashLightUtilForL.java:50)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:118)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

it seems the problem is here `mBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);`

Also my device have flash light and I set Camera permissions

My Class:

```
public class FlashLightUtilForL {
private CameraCaptureSession mSession;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mBuilder;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraManager mCameraManager;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public FlashLightUtilForL(Context context) {
    try {
        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        mCameraManager.openCamera("0", new MyCameraDeviceStateCallback(), null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class MyCameraDeviceStateCallback extends CameraDevice.StateCallback {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice = camera;
        try {

            mBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);
            List<Surface> list = new ArrayList<Surface>();
            Size size = getSmallestSize(mCameraDevice.getId());
            SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(1);

            mSurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            Surface mSurface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
            list.add(mSurface);
            mBuilder.addTarget(mSurface);
            camera.createCaptureSession(list, new MyCameraCaptureSessionStateCallback(), null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private Size getSmallestSize(String cameraId) throws CameraAccessException {
    Size[] outputSizes = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
            .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
            .getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
    if (outputSizes == null || outputSizes.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Camera " + cameraId + "doesn't support any outputSize.");
    }
    Size chosen = outputSizes[0];
    for (Size s : outputSizes) {
        if (chosen.getWidth() >= s.getWidth() && chosen.getHeight() >= s.getHeight()) {
            chosen = s;
        }
    }
    return chosen;
}

/**
 * session callback
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class MyCameraCaptureSessionStateCallback extends CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        mSession = session;
        try {
            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mBuilder.build(), null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void turnOnFlashLight() {
    try {
        if(mBuilder!= null) {
            mBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mBuilder.build(), null, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void turnOffFlashLight() {
    try {
        mBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mBuilder.build(), null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    if (mCameraDevice == null || mSession == null) {
        return;
    }
    mSession.close();
    mCameraDevice.close();
    mCameraDevice = null;
    mSession = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Seems that you have not closed your camera and opened again before create another `captureRequest`, could be?

Comment: I don't use Camera before this . But If  you think Camera is captured by another session or something else, give me a code to check it.Thanks

Comment: for closing camera have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208576/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE` as a template value.

So this template is supported in all camera devices except `DEPTH_OUTPUT` devices that are not backward compatible as mentioned in google documentation.

Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE) :